# Optimize Join Performance of PySpark Dataframes in Databricks Notebook

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am new to databricks and spark env. and working on joining two datasets which are as following:

**1. Dataset#1**
[image]

**2. Dataset#2**

[image]

**What I did so far?**

Came up with following logic to join them

```
datasetDF.alias("datasetDF").join(geoipDF.alias("geoipDF"),datasetDF.ip_address ==  geoipDF.ip_address,"inner").select(col("datasetDF.ip_address"), col("datasetDF.timestamp"),  col("datasetDF.device_type"),  col("datasetDF.email"), col("geoipDF.city"), col("geoipDF.state")).show(truncate=False)
```

But this takes long time to run. Is there something can be done to optimize the performance of this join?

Comment: what is candidate_source? you can try to persist that dataset, also you can try broadcast hint on smaller dataset when you joining.

Comment: @Shankar: `candidate_source` is db name. I am accessing table in databricks as `candidate_source.<table-name>`. Can you suggest how I can use that in this example. (I'm pretty new to databricks env.)

Comment: if you are reading tables using jdbc, and if you want to read the table in parallel, you could use `partitionColumn, lowerBound, upperBound`, most of the times reading table takes more time. refer https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html#data-source-option

Comment: @Shankar: I am not reading them using jdbc. they're in databricks under `data`.

Comment: Difficult to answser, you'll need to investigate what is happening. Do your tables consist of thousands of small files? (try to run opitmize if its a delta table). Are you spilling to disk? (larger cluster/workers), is your data exploding in size? (duplicate ip_addresses in DF1?) etc. Also, if you're not working with dummy data I'd higly recommend masking the ip_address and email fields.